# How to say expedite a process by two times

Tags: grammar, time, mathematics

Let's assume that we have a process that takes 10 minutes to finish. Now, we come up with a new way that can do the process in 2 minutes. A few questions:

1. How can we say this sentence correctly: The new method expedites/speeds up/accelerates the process (by) 5 times?
2. Should we say by 5 times or 4 times?
3. How can we say it in terms of percentages rather than absolute numbers (400% faster)?
4. Supposing the new method actually does the process in 50 minutes, how can we say it along the lines of "The new method slows down the process (by) 5/4 times."?

Answer (score 4):

It is not usual to use "expedite" along with a numeric measure of speed in my experience, although doing so is not **wrong**.

If a new method reduces the time taken from 10 minutes to 2 minutes, that is a 5 times speed up or a 5 times reduction in time taken. I do not see any way that it could be spoken of as 4 times. This could be stated as 500%, but that would be significantly less usual, unless other related changes are all being given on a percentage basis.

Possible valid ways to say this:

> - The new method speeds up the process by a factor of five.
> - The new method accelerates the process by a factor of five.
> - The new method speeds up the process by 500%.
> - The new method makes the process go five times as fast.
> - The new method makes the process take only one-fifth as long.
> - The new method takes only one-fifth as long.
> - The new method is five times faster than the old method.
> - The new method is five times faster.

For the change from 10 minutes to 50 one might say:

> - The new method takes five times as long.
> - The new method slows down the process by a factor of five.
> - The new method is five times slower than the old method.

Comment: Essentially correct. I would avoid "accelerates". For the change from 10 to 50 "Five times slower" is common and understandable but grates on my mathematicians ear.

Comment: @EthanBolker Why does it grate?

Comment: @David Siegel: I asked about 4 times because I have this confusion that when we say this room is two times bigger than that room, do we mean the size of this room is 300 sqft when the other room's size is 100 sqft or 150 sqft (300 = 100 * 2 (two times) + 100)? The meaning of "this room's size is twice the other room's" is not vague to me; it means that the other room is 150 sqft.

Comment: @Diamond It grates because converting 10 to 2 by multiplying (i.e. with "times") calls for a factor of 1/5, not 5. But that is my professional nitpicking. "Five times slower" will be understood.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I also agree that three times four makes 12. My confusion is about when you say 12 is three times bigger than four. One could say that 12 is two times *bigger* than four, but 12 is not two times four.

Comment: @Diamond - In English, we can say that 12 is three times **as big as** four, 12 = **3** x 4, or twice **bigger than** four, 12 = (**2** + 1) x 4 . However, casually, these usages can be interchanged, causing confusion, or worse, sometimes. Unfortunately, many native speakers aren't very good with numbers, and language discussing ratio and difference causes much confusion, e.g. 'twice smaller', 'percent bigger', etc.